# Ubuntu dual boot install hanging up at dots screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04.2 on my laptop, which currently has Windows 10 installed. (Bash on Ubuntu on Windows is not cutting it for what I need) I loaded an external hard drive with a mounted ISO. I have over 40GB unallocated space on my internal hard drive. Trying to go straight to install freezes my computer on the splash screen after the third white dot turns orange. I've tried to find an answer on other questions, but I couldn't find something that worked.

*My system*
 System: Dell Inspiron 3541
 Processor: AMD A6-6310 APU, 64-bit
 Graphics: AMD Radeon R4 Graphics 1.80GHz
 RAM: 8.00GB

I tried adding "nomodeset" on the linux line of the grub loader and instead of the dots freezing after the third one turns orange, I get this.

[image]

I hope someone can at least tell me what's going on, maybe translate that output, if not find out how to get my computer to install it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your BIOS to A07. Go to http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-15-3541-laptop/drivers?os=wt64a

Also try booting the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in "Try Ubuntu" mode and see if it boots up without a kernel panic.

**Update**:

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo update-initramfs -c -k "$(uname -r)"`
- at the # prompt, type `reboot`

Comment: I'm gonna try that. I've tried updating by BIOS a few months ago, however I believe I tried right before this one came out.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/IZ0eX5p.jpg still doing this

Comment: I looked at your imgur image. When did it start doing that? Did you try and boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD, and if yes, did it fully boot to the "Try Ubuntu" mode? Give me a few minutes, and I'll type up and update in my answer that should fix the problem that you're showing me now...